# NSMutableArray and synchronization

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety, nsmutablearray

I am using an NSMutableArray like a Queue.

Imagine that the app is like Tinder, and when stack of Cards go below a number I fetch new data. When fetching data, they are added at the end of the NSMutableArray. When swiping, I remove fron object.

Should I synchronize these actions?

Here is sample code :

```
//.. fetching from ParseAPI
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
           //....get object
           [_cards addObject:object];
        }
```

and the delegate method from swiping.

```
- (MyCustomView *)popViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
...
[self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Since enqueueing happens always at the end, and dequeuing at the front, should I provide any locks or synchronisations between these accesses?

If yes, how should I do that?

I guess I should provide some synchronisation on some NSLog I have for debugging purposes.

Comment: Depends - are you accessing array from multiple threads? No need for synchronisation otherwise. (Im not sure about Parse, but most networking frameworks deliver results on main thread).

Comment: In addition to knowing how many threads attempt to modify the contents of the array, you should also avoid mixing property access and direct ivar access. Use the property syntax in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [All Parse completion blocks should execute on the main thread.](https://parse.com/questions/what-thread-does-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-complete-on)

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // main thread here
}];
```

So the completion block is executed on main thread, it means you don't nead any synchronisation.

Answer (score -1):

If you modify an NSArray on one thread and you either access or modify the NSArray from another thread, the access must be synchronised. No problem if you access and modify it on the main thread, or on the same serial queue.

Comment: NSArray is immutable, so you can only access it. it means NSArray can be accessed from all the threads without any syncronisation. Here you can see that `NSArray` is thread safe https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html